# Cygwin not installing properly

Tags: installation, cygwin

I've downloaded Cygwin [here](https://cygwin.com/install.html)( setup-x86_64.exe). I have chosen to install from local directory. 
Root directory: C:\cygwin64 . Local package directory: C:\Users\hp\Downloads. And there's no packages to install. How do I fix this? mintty.exe does not exist on my bin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you choose “Install from Local Directory”, Cygwin will try to pull packages
from your cache. In my case, my cache is:

```
C:\ProgramData
```

My mirror is:

```
http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com/
```

and my packages can be found:

```
C:\ProgramData\http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f\x86_64\release
C:\ProgramData\http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f\noarch\release
```

Unless you have stuff there, you will be unable to install anything. Better
option is to choose “Install from Internet”. This will download
packages if needed.

Comment: thank you it's now working! When I tried the Install from Internet i chose the desktop directory, it should be the downloads directory.